# Drop item in an empty space using jQuery Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I m using `jQuery Sortable` and it works well.
But I am getting a small issue over here.
    I have two blocks where elements of one block can be moved to another.But the problem is, when all the elements of right-side block are moved to left-side block and now I am unable to move any element from left-side block to right-side block since right-side block does not have any empty space,I guess.
*Blocks before elements are moved completely*
[image]

*Blocks after right-side block elements are moved to left*
[image]
Now, I am unable to move element from left-side block to right-side block.

So is there any way to preserve an empty space in the empty block(right-side block in the 2nd image) or any other alternative solution?

**Here is my code and [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wY4ja/).**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <style>
  body{
   margin:10px;
  }
  table{
   width:100%;
  }
  .gridWrapper{
   border-collapse:collapse;
  }
  .gridWrapper,.gridWrapper tr  td.column{
    border:2px solid red;
    vertical-align:top;
  }
   .grid{
     border-collapse:collapse;
    *border-spacing:10px;
   }
   .grid td{
     border:1px dashed black;
     white-space:nowrap;
     padding:3px 5px;
   }
   .ui-state-highlight{
     height: 1.5em;
     line-height: 1.2em;
   }
  .grid td:first-child{
      text-align: right;
      font-weight: bold;
  }
  td.column{
     width:50%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <table class="gridWrapper">
  <tr>
   <td class="column">
  <table id="sort1" class="grid" title="Kurt Vonnegut novels">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Name</td><td>Will Smith</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Date of Birth</td><td>25/09/1968</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zodiac Sign</td><td>Libra</td></tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
<td class="column">
  <table id="sort2" class="grid" title="Kurt Vonnegut novels">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Occupation</td><td>Actor,Producer</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Place of birth</td><td>Philadelphia</td></tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
 <script>
  $(".grid tbody").sortable({
       connectWith:'.grid tbody',
       placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
       dropOnEmpty: true,
       helper: function(e, ui) {
                    ui.children().each(function() {
                        $(this).width($(this).width());
                    });
                    return ui;
                },
        forceHelperSize: true
  }).disableSelection();
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is quite strange: ` $(this).width($(this).width());` But for sure not related to your issue. Basically, you should set a jsfiddle for this kind of question.

Comment: @roasted I have found that helper code in google which resolved td width problem while dragging. It doesn't hurt the rest of the functionality.

Comment: @roasted edited with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Its an ugly hack making your tbody a block level element and giving it a min-height.

```
.grid tbody{
    min-height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wY4ja/2/). I would advise against use of tables for sorting as manipulating tables is tough. Make use of divs and li's to display that data.

Comment: Yeah, Its a some kind of thing that works but tbody width is set to it's content size regardless of size that I wish to set...

Comment: I fixed your width issue but it is causing problems during sorting. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wY4ja/3/. My best bet would be to avoid using tables.